# Are there any known Java implementations for OAuth2 'mac' token type?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, hmac

I have looked into various OAuth2 java libraries (spring-security-oauth, cxf, scribe, google-oauth-java-client) and could not find anything out there that supports the Mac token type as described here:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-01

All of them support the Bearer token type by default and nothing else. Is there any particular reason why this token type is not supported at all?

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind most of the Java libraries for `OAuth 2.0` supports `Bearer` token types is that `Bearer` Token profile brings a simplified scheme for authentication. Any user which has a `bearer` token can use it to get access to the associated resources (without demonstrating possession of a cryptographic key). The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: `Bearer` Token Usage specifications describes the use of `bearer` tokens in `HTTP` `requests` to access OAuth 2.0 protected resources.

Response for `Bearer` Access Token

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
     Cache-Control: no-store
     Pragma: no-cache

     {
       "access_token":"mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM",
       "token_type":"Bearer",
       "expires_in":3600,
       "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA"
      }
```

`MAC` Token Profile defines the `HTTP` `MAC` access authentication scheme, providing a method for making authenticated HTTP requests with partial cryptographic verification of the request, covering the HTTP method, request URI, and host. Each access token type definition specifies the additional attributes (`mac_key`, `mac_algorithm`) sent to the client together with the `access_token` response parameter.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     Content-Type: application/json
     Cache-Control: no-store

     {
       "access_token":"SlAV32hkKG",
       "token_type":"mac",
       "expires_in":3600,
       "refresh_token":"8xLOxBtZp8",
       "mac_key":"adijq39jdlaska9asud",
       "mac_algorithm":"hmac-sha-256"
     }
```

The `access_token` or the `MAC` key identifier is a string identifying the `MAC` key used to calculate the request `MAC`. The string is usually opaque to the client. The server typically assigns a specific scope and lifetime to each set of `MAC` credentials. The identifier may denote a unique value used to retrieve the authorization information (e.g. from a database), or self-contain the authorization information in a verifiable manner (i.e. a string consisting of some data and a signature).

[**Scribe**](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) is the library in Java for `OAuth 2.0` with `MAC` Token profile.

Source: [OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token Profile Vs MAC Token Profile](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2013/01/oauth-20-bearer-token-profile-vs-mac.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this field, but I seem to be under the impression that [PicketLink](http://picketlink.org/) supports both MAC and BEARER [token types](https://github.com/picketlink/picketlink/blob/783ea51b00c4985c90a8440abbde0848ddeb3a84/modules/oauth/src/main/java/org/picketlink/oauth/messages/AccessTokenResponse.java#L37).

I'm not really sure it is what you want. If you have any doubts, you can [contact them here](http://picketlink.org/gethelp/).